# PostGIS -> LineString + PointZ = LineStringZ

Tags: postgis, postgresql, 3d, nearest-neighbor, knn

**DATA**

I have 2 tables in PostGIS:

- *`linestable`* with MultiLineString geom
- *`surveypointtable`* with Point + elevation attribute

**GOAL**

The goal is to rebuild the lines as 3D replacing line's vertices with the closets surveypoint.

**LOGIC**

1. Rebuild points as PointZ and get the collection of all points

   ```
   ST_Collect(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(geom),ST_Y(geom),elevation_att))
   ```
2. Get line's vertices as points using

   ```
   ST_DumpPoints(geom).geom
   ```
3. Find closest surveypoint using

   ```
   ST_ClosestPoint(surveypoints.geom, linepoints.geom)
   ```
4. Check if the closestpoint is within 1m using

   ```
   ST_DWithin(surveypoints.geom, linepoints.geom, 1)
   ```
5. Build line using only the closets surveypoints that are within 1m tolerance.

   ```
   ST_MakeLine(ST_Collect(closestpoints.geom))
   ```

**PROBLEM**

When I use `ST_ClosestPoint(p.3)` it drops the z-index of the point and as a result I end up with a 2D line.

When I use `ST_3DClosestPoint` it takes wrong points - i.e. if I had point A 1m away in 2D from linepoint but at the same elevation and point B at the exact same coordinates as linepoint but with 10m difference in elevation it would take point A.

**CODE**

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newlines;


    CREATE TABLE newlines AS
    SELECT gid,
          ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeLine(geom),27700)
    FROM
      (SELECT gid,
              path,
              ST_AsText(
                ST_Collect(
                  closestsurveypoint)) AS geom
      FROM
        ( SELECT linepoints.gid AS gid,
                  linepoints.path AS path,
                  linepoints.geom AS linepoint,
                  (CASE ST_DWithin(
                        ST_SetSRID(surveypoints.geom, 27700), 
                        ST_SetSRID(linepoints.geom, 27700), 
                        1)
                      WHEN TRUE THEN ST_AsText(
                        ST_ClosestPoint(
                          ST_SetSRID(surveypoints.geom, 27700), 
                          ST_SetSRID(linepoints.geom, 27700) ))
                  END) AS closestsurveypoint
          FROM
            ( SELECT gid,
                    color, 
                    (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path AS path,
                    ST_AsText((ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom) AS geom
            FROM linestable) AS linepoints,

            ( SELECT ST_AsText(
              ST_Collect(
                ST_MakePoint(
                  ST_X(geom), 
                  ST_Y(geom), 
                  elevation))) AS geom
            FROM surveypointstable) AS surveypoints ) AS newlinepoints
      GROUP BY gid,
                path
      ORDER BY gid,
                path) AS newlines
    GROUP BY gid
```

Comment: Have you tried using ST_Force3D?  I have found with certain 3D operations, I had to wrap everything in such calls to get correct behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create `POINTZ` to extrapolate the elevation; instead, find the nearest neighbor of your *`surveypointtable`* to each vertex of `linestable` first, then create `POINTZ` from each vertex with that respective elevation attribute and stitch the lines back together via row number and the *path* sequence of `ST_DumpPoints`:

```
WITH
    seqs AS (
        SELECT --pts.<some_column>, pts.<some_other_column>,
               mln_seq,
               pts.path[1] AS elem_seq,
               pts.path[2] AS pnt_seq,
               pts.geom AS geom
        FROM (
            SELECT --<some_column>, <some_other_column>, 
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS mln_seq,
                   (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).*
            FROM linestable
        ) AS pts
    )

SELECT DISTINCT
       --s.<some_column>, s.<some_other_column>,
       ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(s.geom), ST_Y(s.geom), q.elevation)) OVER(PARTITION BY s.mln_seq, s.elem_seq ORDER BY s.elem_seq) AS geom
FROM seqs AS s
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT elevation
    FROM surveypointtable
    ORDER BY geom <-> s.geom
    LIMIT 1
) AS q
ON true;
```

I included `<some_column>, <some_other_column>` for the *`linestable`*; replace and uncomment if you intent to keep attributes from your original lines.

Note that you will have to set *SRID*s as necessary; have a look in the tags [nearest-neighbor](/questions/tagged/nearest-neighbor) and [knn](/questions/tagged/knn) for [postgis](/questions/tagged/postgis) to find info on the used structure (`LATERAL JOIN`), including detailed description of proper CRS/unit usage and the `<->` *KNN* operator.

Note also that I assume your initial lines are `MULTILINESTRINGs`, since you said so; the result will be simple `LINESTRINGZs`, as your title suggests. Honestly, I am not sure what you have and expect...but this should work with `LINESTIRNGs` as input if you remove all references to `pnt_seq` from above (i.e. `pts.path[2]`, as there will only be one sequence number in *path*), and you can `ST_Collect` the result grouped by `mln_seq` if you need `MULTILINESTRINGZs`; then, however, you cannot keep attributes as simple as above.

Comment: ah, btw. if you want to create a new table, you can simply add `CREATE TABLE AS ...` before the `SELECT DISTINCT ...`, i.e. you can use CTEs for table creation queries.

Comment: WoW! This is BRILLIANT! It works like a charm, thank you very much.

Comment: I have one more question - what happens if it doesn't find a point or point is with NULL elevation?

Comment: And answering your question - I have     MultiLineString in my linestable but can work with    LineStrings as the query's output.

Comment: @ŁukaszKłosiński it will *always* find *a* point...if there is at least *one* point in your *`surveypointtable`*; you even have the option to define a `WHERE` filter in the `LATERAL` sub-query, e.g. if you want to consider only points with a matching column value etc. for each line. as to the `NULL` value: it will probably throw an error in `ST_MakePoint`; use `SELECT COALESCE(elevation, <default_value>) ...` instead of `SELECT elevation ...` in the sub-query to catch that case.