# PostGIS -> LineString + PointZ = LineStringZ - Misjoined segments

Tags: postgis

I have used modified version of a querry from this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299346/postgis-linestring-pointz-linestringz) (I work on linestrings) and have came across few issues:

- if I run the querry on my table it doesn't join the segments back in the right order
- if I modify the querry modify ORDER BY from multiline_seq to multiline_seq, lineseq it joins the segments back in the right order but creates ca. 25000 features rather than expected ca. 1500
- if I limit the noumber of rows with WHERE statement it works fine

**MY QUERY**:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS util_div_lines_3D;

CREATE TABLE util_div_lines_3D AS

WITH
    util_div_lines_vertices AS (
            SELECT
                    gid,
                    dxf3d,
                    layer,
                    color,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS multiline_seq,
                    (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path[1] AS line_seq,
                    (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom AS geom
            FROM util_div_lines
    )

SELECT DISTINCT
        gid,
        dxf3d,
        layer,
        color,
        multiline_seq,
        ST_MakeLine(
            ST_SetSRID(
            ST_MakePoint(
            ST_X(geom),
            ST_Y(geom),
            nearest_survey_point.elevation
            ),
            27700)) OVER (PARTITION BY multiline_seq ORDER BY multiline_seq) AS geom
FROM util_div_lines_vertices
JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
            (
            CASE ST_DWithin(geom, util_div_lines_vertices.geom, 0.01)
            WHEN TRUE THEN elevation
            ELSE -999
            END
            ) AS elevation
    FROM util_div_survey_points
    ORDER BY geom <-> util_div_lines_vertices.geom
    LIMIT 1
) AS nearest_survey_point
ON true
WHERE dxf3d = 'YES'
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT
[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

OUTPUT FROM MY QUERRY
[image: OUTPUT FROM MY QUERRY]

Comment: Try `ORDER BY line_seq` in `ST_MakeLine`'s `OVER()` statement.

Comment: i have tried that. I get exactly the same resuts.

Comment: Sorry, how does the correct query including limiting the rows in the where statement look?

Comment: @JohnPowell the code is exactly the same the only difference is the last line
instead of
WHERE dxf3d = 'YES'
I have
WHERE dxf3d = 'YES' and gid<1498