# set z-value from table

Tags: postgis, qgis-3, 3d, linestring, z-value

In qgis 3, postgis, no DEM and zero python knowledge.
I've got linestring 3d but Z coordinates is empty, Z-values are stored in table.
Z1 for the first node, Z2 for the last node.
I found a lot of ways to extract Z to populate the table but never opposite.
I try "set Z value" processing, but I can't assign value Z1 to first point and Z2 to last point.
I turn around with start_point, end_point,st_z, maybe st_makeline and others but I can't do it.

Answer (score 1):

In case your lines are two vertice segments, this simply translates into

```
UPDATE <table>
  SET geom = ST_SetSRID(
               ST_MakeLine(
                 ST_MakePoint(
                   ST_X(ST_StartPoint(geom)),
                   ST_Y(ST_StartPoint(geom)),
                   "Z1":: FLOAT
                 ),
                 ST_MakePoint(
                   ST_X(ST_EndPoint(geom)),
                   ST_Y(ST_EndPoint(geom)),
                   "Z2":: FLOAT
                 )
               ),
               <SRID>
             )
;
```

*Verbosely written for reference.*

In case your LineStrings are polylines (with >2 vertices), this is a lot more involved.

Comment: Thk. Unfortunately, I've got polylines. And I wish I didn't have to redraw.

Comment: I try to compile your response with https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299346/postgis-linestring-pointz-linestringz but I fly...

Comment: @pasqal that's not the way to go. You want to interpolate height based on the fraction of linelength at which every point of your lines resides, over the slope of the line between start and end points. I have been to lazy to include that in my answer...

Comment: ok, no problem ;-) I thinking about creating pointz layers with my linestring to re-introduce values after.